# Help Prove the equality of sets. I know very little math analysis

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$ (B\setminus A)\cup(C\setminus  A) = (B\cup C)\setminus  A$$

I found a very similar example but it was De Morgan's law. I would like to be explained and shown how this example is solved

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, this just says that if an element is either in $B$ but not $A$ or in $C$ but not $A$, then either way it must be in $B$ or in $C$ and cannot be in $A$.  Conversely if it is in $B$ or $C$, but not in $A$ then either it must be in $B$ but not $A$ or $C$ but not $A$.

Formally you can prove this by considering the $8$ cases for inclusion in $A,B,C$ and showing that in each case an element is in the LHS in precisely the same cases as when it is in the RHS.

I'll get you started with one row of the table:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|cc}
A&B&C&B\backslash A&C \backslash A & B\cup C& (B\backslash A)\cup(C \backslash A) &(B\cup C)\backslash A\\\hline
0&1&0&1&0&1&1&1
\end{array}
$$